# Is it possible to write this SQL query shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have excercise to get data from MySql. Two tables 'producers' and 'products'. Task content:

The name of the manufacturer will appear in the first column.
In the second column  will apear % of products
of a given manufacturer for all products. Third column
has the average number of products of a given manufacturer per day.
Products that do not have a manufacturer ID number (producer_id = NULL) belong
qualify as "Other"(there is not 'Other' in producers table) and present in the statement.
All data will depend on date which is selected by user for example, user need statement from '2017-03-28' to '2017-03-30' or another example from '2017-03-29' to '2017-03-29'

I wrote this query. This is working fine but in my opinion is too long.

```
SELECT producers.producer_name AS producer, 
CONCAT(ROUND((SELECT COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products WHERE products.producer_id = producers.producer_id AND products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30') * 100 / 
(SELECT COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products where products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30')), '%') AS '% share',
ROUND((SELECT COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products WHERE products.producer_id = producers.producer_id AND products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30') /
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT products.product_date) FROM products WHERE products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30')) AS 'day avg'

FROM products, producers
GROUP BY producers.producer_name
UNION

SELECT 'other' AS producer,
CONCAT(ROUND((SELECT COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products WHERE products.producer_id = 'null'AND products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30') * 100 / 
(select COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products WHERE products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30')), '%') AS '% share',
ROUND((SELECT COUNT(products.product_name) FROM products WHERE products.producer_id = 'null' AND products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30') /
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT products.product_date) FROM products WHERE products.product_date BETWEEN '2017-03-28' AND '2017-03-30')) AS 'day avg'
FROM products
```

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`producer_id` INT(11) NULL,
`product_url` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
`product_name` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
`product_price` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_price_old` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_reviews` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`product_rating` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
INDEX `product_date_producer_id` (`producer_id`, `product_date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `producers` (
`producer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`producer_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`producer_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Good question, it has `Create Table ...` statements to show what it's all about, mentions the name of the `DBMS`, and shows what you tried which works for you. Only one thing is missing IMO: Sample Data as a few `Insert Into ...` lines for the two tables and the expected result, say three or ten rows of it

Comment: For testing changes to a relatively large, complicated query, please provide not only inputs, but a link to a working fiddle (like on dbfiddle.uk) for a place for the potential answerer to start.